# v2ray (vmess|vless|trojan|ss) test in python

Tags: python-3.x, networking, vpn, l2tp

Friends, how can I test the configurations of (**vmess**|**vless**|**trojan**|**ss**) with Python?

I need a function to test the speed of given v2ray configs

Answer (score 2):

There is a project [vmessping](https://github.com/v2fly/vmessping) by v2fly that support only vmess but there is a [LiteSpeedTest](https://github.com/xxf098/LiteSpeedTest) for trojan/ss

sample:

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def speedtest(vmesslink):
    process = Popen(["./vmessspeed", vmesslink], stdout=PIPE)
    stdout = process.communicate()[0]

    return stdout
```